# PHPStorm unusable after crash

Tags: phpstorm

Today PHPStorm crashed out of the blue during some Javascripting.

After restart, nothing works: I can't open preferences nor files.

Files are no longer associated with Editors:

[image]

I restarted my MAC and have reinstalled PHPStorm - no luck. Since the latter did remember my registration details, I assume I missed something on deleting PHPStorm.

I have absolutely no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely configuration/plugins files are corrupted, you can delete or rename the following directories to start with the defaults:

- **Settings**: `~/Library/Preferences/WebIde50`
- **Caches**: `~/Library/Caches/WebIde50`
- **Plugins**: `~/Library/Application Support/WebIde50`

Other users with similar problems on another systems or with different IntelliJ IDEA platform based products can refer to [this document](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to find the location of these folders on their system.